# Bad request at Azure Automation Tasks Preview

Tags: azure, azure-automation

I've created a bunch of tasks to stop, deallocate and restart some VMs at Azure, and they work but all of them are reported as a failure because the execution block on the logic app workflow keeps throwing an 400 Bad Request Error.

Anyone else getting these symptoms?

[image]

Error code:

"`{ "error": { "code": 400, "source": "logic-apis-brazilsouth.azure-apim.net", "clientRequestId": "XXXX", "message": "The response is not in a JSON format.", "innerError": "<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN\"\"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd\">\r\n<HTML><HEAD><TITLE>Bad Request</TITLE>\r\n<META HTTP-EQUIV=\"Content-Type\" Content=\"text/html; charset=us-ascii\"></HEAD>\r\n<BODY><h2>Bad Request - Request Too Long</h2>\r\n<hr><p>HTTP Error 400. The size of the request headers is too long.</p>\r\n</BODY></HTML>\r\n" } }`"

Answer (score 0):

It works for me, To Deallocate VM using that action you need to correctly select the existed vm from the drop down or else you can click on enter a custom value and enter the names or you can use string variable which contains name.

Design:

[image]

[image]
Output:

[image]